# Storing vim plugins in Linux

Tags: vim, plugins

Usually all vim plugins are stored in the `/$HOME/.vim` directory.

As I understand the plugins share common folders like `plugin`, `autoload`, `doc` etc. It's a problem when you have to delete some plugins.

Is it possible to store vim plugins separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, that is possible. you could either hack your own way around it or use [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332).

the point is that vim searches for the plugins by trying the [runtimepath](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27runtimepath%27). so, you could tell vim to treat the subfolders of a directory called, lets say, 'voodoo' as plugins and append the path to these subfolders to the runtimepath. voila.

read more about the topic [here](http://tammersaleh.com/posts/the-modern-vim-config-with-pathogen).

Comment: does it work only for those plugins that are on github? you just clone the repository to bundle directory and that's all. What if the plugin(for example fuzzyfinder) is not on git and is available as .zip archive?

Comment: it works for any plugin. you drop the files of each external plugin into a subfolder of the special folder used by pathogen (or you use a customized path, i use `3rd`). done.

Answer (score 0):

No need to edit anything IMO. Just store them anywhere you want but add a soft link in */$HOME/.vim* (ln -s)

Comment: so you want him to `ln -s` the `.vim/3rd/foo1/plugin/foo.vim` to `.vim/plugin/foo.vim` and then  the `.vim/3rd/foo1/doc/foo.txt` to `.vim/doc/foo.txt` and then the same for all the other plugins as well? what about the mess you have to clean up now on uninstallation of  `foo1`? bad answer, imho.

Comment: You can easily script the uninstallation process, but yes, you might be right :)